# How to install Apache2::AuthCookie in CentOS version 6?

Tags: apache, perl, centos

I am trying to install [`Apache2::AuthCookie`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::AuthCookie) Perl module in CentOS v6.5 but I cannot make it. I have tried

```
# yum install 'perl(Apache2::AuthCookie)'
```

But no success.

Any idea?

Comment: and you're certain that the yum package isn't named something like perl-apache2-authcookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using cpan minus. First Install [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm) itself, like this:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

Then simply:

```
cpanm Apache2::AuthCookie
```